# Objective C - Order NSArray with correct date format

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have an NSArray with objects that have a property called "dueDate" every object has a date assigned which is a NSString, but there are objects where the dueDate is "-" (meaning the user didn't add a specific date), I must reorder the NSArray so the objects with the "-" dueDate are ALWAYS at the bottom, and the ones with a specific date are ordered ascending and at the top of the NSArray.

here is the NSArray and an example of the data of the objects:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So?  Review the documentation for NSArray/NSMutableArray.  There are several `sortedArrayUsing...` methods that you can use to produce any sort sequence you want.

Comment: Why isn't `dueDate` an `NSDate` instead of an `NSString`? Would make a lot of things much easier.

Comment: You can always convert it to NSDate, but one of your main issues is the date format in the string:  It could be 08/03/2014 or 8/3/2014, (or really any other format...8/03/2014 or Aug 3,2014) and since it's a string, you'll have to parse it first.  Once you can tell which date really is bigger than another, than you can use a custom comparator as below to do the actual sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sortedArrayUsingComparator:`. You would do something like this

```
NSArray *sortedByDueDate = [toBeSortedByDueAte sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id lhs, id rhs) {
    SavedTask *lhs_task = (SavedTask *)lhs;
    SavedTask *rhs_task = (SavedTask *)rhs;
    NSString *lhs_dueDate = lhs_task.dueDate;
    NSString *rhs_dudDate = rhs_task.dueDate;
    NSComparisonResult const result = /* Your code for comparing the strings here */
    return result
}];
```

In production code you should verify that `lhs` and `rhs` are of the expected type.